# How do you use scalacss with scalatags in scala 3?

Tags: scala-3, scalatags

In scala 2.13, the library com.github.japgolly.scalacss ext-scalatags_2.13 supports using scalacss with scalatags. Scalacss has been ported to scala 3 but it doesn't appear that ext-scalatags has. Is it possible to use scalacss with scalatags in scala 3?